# MEAN Stack Setup - Command Line

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mean-stack

I'm trying to set up a MEAN application and am having some trouble understanding how to go about doing this. I am using Windows, which I know is not ideal, but we're playing around with the MEAN stack at an Enterprise level and that is my only option. I also have very limited experience working with the command line. My biggest areas of frustration are knowing how/where to execute command line commands (please don't tell me the command line). One issue I have is trying to install MEAN on my local pc - I am informed that the prerequisite Git is not installed. I run npm (I have successfully installed Node) install Git, it appears that it is installed, yet I still cannot init a mean app due to the same error. Another issue I have is where we have installed a mean app on a server, however the mean command is not recognized. Where would I go to install a new mean app? How would I install a mean package (what I'm really trying to do)? How do I get MEAN recognized, if I know we have already used it? How many different command prompts should I be using (Git Bash, Windows CLI, Node command prompt)? I feel like an idiot asking such basic questions, but I have literally been trying to figure this out for months and I still don't get it. In case you can't tell, my frustration level is ever increasing. Any help or links to spelled out tutorials would be helpful. I'm tired of seeing 'execute this command' and it never working out as a tut or blog suggests. What am I missing???

Comment: http://www.matthewrmonroe.com/installing-the-mean-stack-on-windows-vista/

Comment: You used npm to install Git?  I develop Node.js apps on Windows as well, and I don't know what that `mean` script is on the page linked to by Stevo... but you probably don't need it.  Node.js has a nice Windows installer.  MongoDB has an installer these days too, or you can just download the binaries.  I haven't used Nginx on Windows as it is considered experimental at the moment.  If you need Nginx as well, I suggest starting up a VM under VirtualBox or something.  Vagrant is a good tool for using VMs in the development process, and it works great under Windows!

Comment: I wrote a tutorial for beginners to get started with the MEAN stack. I tested out the steps using Powershelgl and Git Bash on Windows. It may be of use to you to follow (in particular the setup), since it's difficult to answer your question specifically. Here's the link: http://www.bradoncode.com/tutorials/mean-stack-tutorial-part-1-setup/

Answer (score 0):

As the other answer hinted, perhaps you need to install Git using WinGit rather than npm. When installing, make sure it is available to all users on the PC.

Otherwise you may have to investigate adding Git to your PATH environment variable in Advanced System Properties in My Computer.

Once you've installed MEAN in a folder, all you should need to do is drop to the command line and move to that folder using CD (e.g. cd \code\mymeanapp), and then just run 'grunt' from there, which will check all your code and fire up your MEAN app.